# Web Speech APIについて

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Web Speech APIについての質問です。

下記の認識で正しいでしょうか？

1. Web Speech APIとは仕様である
2. webkitSpeechRecognitionは、Web Speech APIを実装したものである
3. webkitSpeechRecognitionは、Chromeで使用可能なjavascriptクラスである
4. webkitSpeechRecognitionとgoogle speech APIは別物である

Answer (score 1):

[Web Speech API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/webspeechapi.html) は [SpeechAPI Community Group](https://www.w3.org/community/speech-api/) によって公開されたAPIの仕様です。

この仕様では音声認識を行う SpeechRecognition と、音声合成を行う SpeechSynthesis の二つのAPIを定義しています。このうち前者の SpeechRecognition が、Chromeでは webkitSpeechRecognition として提供されています。この webkitSpeechRecognition は前述の SpeechRecognition インターフェイスを実装したクラス、と言えるかと思います。

ちなみに SpeechSynthesis の方はChromeでもプレフィックスなしですが、そもそもこっちは window.speechSynthesis から取得するので、直接名前を意識することもないと思います。

参考 [Web Speech API - Web API インターフェイス | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API)

一方 Google Speech API は、Chromium ブラウザ用のAPIで、Maps API や Drive API のようにHTTP経由で利用します。使い方はググると出てきますが、前述のとおり一般向けのAPIではありません。[Chromiumの開発者MLの参加者にのみトークンが発行されます](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26485531/2818869)し、呼び出し回数制限も厳しいです。